# Get System.Web.HttpResponse from a class which does not extend System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, response, webmethod

Though the title says everything, I want to let you know the particular scenario where I need this.

In application I want to logout an user by calling a JavaScript method. This method in turns is calling a WebMethod:

```
namespace EMSApplication.Web.WebServices {
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the Webservice methods of EMSApplication
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://ems-app.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class EMSWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {   

        [WebMethod]
        public string Logout() {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ==JYM00000000000000000000000000000");
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
        }
        return "";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Response.Redirect will create a 302 Http Response which for the browser means it will need to redirect the user to that new location.

Since now the call is made from javascript, the JavaScript needs to interpret the response and to instruct the browser to load the new location.

The easiest way I'm thinking now is the Logout() method to return the new location and JavaScript will set the window.location property

```
window.location = msg.d;
```

From an WebService you can access the Response from HttpContext class (`HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect()`), but you won't need that. Actually I don't think that a webservice should write another response than the usual ones (SOAP, etc).

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response
```

This is a static property.